# How to pushed users to use proxy?

Tags: windows-domain, squid, proxy-server

i have configured **SQUID PROXY** on CentoS 7

Now i need to force all users on domain controller to use proxy(but some users dont use the proxy)
Any idea to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what OS the end users are using, followed by their IE Version. You can run a GPO to force user to use a proxy, you may want to [read this.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5156.how-to-force-proxy-settings-via-group-policy.aspx)

Ideally, you may also just have a login script that does something similar to:

> Regedit4
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings] "MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001 "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
>   "ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000000
>   "ProxyServer"="http://ProxyServername:80" "ProxyOverride"=""

You can read up on this [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961).